# 거 in the phrase 재미있는 게임을 하는 거예요

Tags: grammar

A: 이번주말에 보령 머드축제에같이 갈래요? 
B: 보령 머드 축제요? 그게 뭐예요?
A: 보령에서 하는 축제예요. 진흙이 있는 해수욕장에서 **재미있는 게임을 하는 거예요**. 그 진흙이 피부에 이주 좋아요.

I am a bit confused about the grammar and meaning of the boldfaced phrase. 
게임을 하다  = to play game
재미있는 게임 = interesting game
거: the contracted form of 것
So what is the meaning of 것 and the phrase?

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at these: https://www.italki.com/question/354764?hl=ko, https://www.howtostudykorean.com/unit-2-lower-intermediate-korean-grammar/unit-2-lessons-26-33/lesson-26/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"xx하는 것" is a common way of saying "doing X" (or "the act of doing X").  So the whole sentence is:

> **진흙이 있는 해수욕장에서 재미있는 게임을 하는 거**예요:
>
> [It] is (the activity of) **playing fun games in a beach with mud.**

Basically, the sentence is structured as "it is (doing X)", but the subject ("보령에서 하는 축제") is omitted because it's obvious from the context.

Answer (score 1):

것 or 거 has four meanings or usages.

1. 것 = Thing

#### 그거, 이거, 저거

2. ㄹ 거예요. = will + verb

#### 갈 거예요 / 잘 거예요. / 먹을 거예요.

3. ㄴ 거 / ㄹ 거 = Verb-ing / To + verb   (ref. -고 싶어요. = I want to -)

#### 걷는 거 좋아해요. / 놀 거 없어요? / 하는 거 좋아해요. / 할 거 없어요?

#### 공부하는 건 어려워요. / 저는 공부하는 걸 좋아해요.

#### ( 건 = 거는/것은, 걸 = 거를/것을)

4. ㄹ 거/ㄴ 거 = [that S + V] as noun(subject or object)

#### 아빠가 아침에 밥을 먹는 걸 보기 힘들어요.

#### 형이 공부하는 걸 본 적이 없어요.

#### 저녁에 사람들이 운동하는 것은 좋아 보여요.

#### 제가 학생들에게 바라는 것은 학생들이 공부할 것들을 미리 준비하는 거예요.

#### 할 수 있을 거 같아요.

If you want quicker answer, we can help out here: https://discord.gg/j9Knkyc

Answer (score 0):

거예요 = 것이에요

것 means "thing".

so 재미있는 게임을 하는 거예요 means "thing that play interesting game."

In here, thing means 보령 머드 축제.